# Show $S^\lambda \otimes sgn$ is a simple representation of $S^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, integer-partitions

> Let $\lambda \vdash n$. Identify $S^\lambda \otimes sgn$ as a simple representation of $S^n$.

I know that that $S^\lambda$ is the Specht module (over $\mathbb{C}$) with a set of polytabloids as a basis depending on the partition $\lambda$ of $n$. I want to show that $S^\lambda$ is invariant under the action of $S_n$, which shouldn't be too difficult, and that it does not contain a sub-module invariant under the action of $S_n$. This second part is what I'm not sure how to approach. This would give me that $S^\lambda$ would correspond to a simple representation of $S_n$, and when tensored with a 1 dimensional representation, it would give me another simple representation.

Comment: If $V$ is a simple representation of a finite group $G$ and $L$ is a simple one-dimensional representation, then $V \otimes L$ is simple again. Intuitively, this is because $L$ has a dual $L^*$ such that $L \otimes L^*$ is (isomorphic to) the trivial representation, hence $(V \otimes L) \otimes L^* \cong V$. Then it is plain to see that $V$ is simple if and only if $V \otimes L$ is. In the case of the sign representation, it is actually self-dual (as is every representation of $S_n$), and furthermore it's interesting to find the $\mu$ such that $S^\lambda \otimes sgn \cong S^\mu$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. That is a wonderful response, but I'm still not sure how to show that the Specht module $S^\lambda$ is a simple representation.

Comment: Ah, sorry for missing that part. This argument often depends on how the theory is developed - rather than looking at polytabloids, looking at Young symmetrisers can be faster. The first account I read was in _Young Tableaux_ by William Fulton, but there are many books which give a proof in various ways. If you would like a proof here, you might need to give a few more details of the construction.